# how to resolve Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs - external library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

when I build my project I get an error - `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`.

When I looked at the merger manifest, error is on external library `instabug` which has a intent-filter and I need to add `android:exported="true"`

how can I fix this without adding this to external library instabug.

error

```
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.instabug.bug.view.reporting.ReportingContainerActivity>
```

instabug manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name="com.instabug.bug.view.reporting.ReportingContainerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/InstabugSdkTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="instabug-disclaimer.com"
                    android:scheme="instabug-bug" />
                <data
                    android:host="instabug-disclaimer.com"
                    android:scheme="repro-steps-disclaimer" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

instabug version in project

```
implementation("com.instabug.library:instabug:10.4.1")

   compileSdkVersion(32)
   minSdkVersion(23)
   targetSdkVersion(32)
```

could you please suggest how I can fix this please.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways I think you can do that, but I'm not sure if the 1st one will work:

1. Copy the `com.instabug.bug.view.reporting.ReportingContainerActivity` declaration  from the library source Manifest into your own Manifest. And then in your own manifest, set the `exported` flag. AS I said, I'm not sure if that will actually compile, but it's worth a try
2. Remove the instabug implementation() directive from your gradle, then download the full source code, and import that source code it into your app as a library. You can then fully edit the Manifest for that library. The downside of this approach is that you can't easily update the library. You would have to re-download the source every time there's a new version, and then modify the Manifest again